# How to restrict a mongo user from dropping a collection?

Tags: mongodb

What would be the configuration/command for creating a role which can be applied to a user in MongoDB so that the user is unable to drop a collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the mongoDB documentation for creating user roles and privileges.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/

In general, for a non-admin role, only providing `read` access will prevent a user from dropping a collection. The code below is taken from the mongo docs and demonstrates access modifications for various collections.

```
use reporting
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "reportsUser",
      pwd: "12345678",
      roles: [
         { role: "read", db: "reporting" },
         { role: "read", db: "products" },
         { role: "read", db: "sales" },
         { role: "readWrite", db: "accounts" }
      ]
    }
)
```

Comment: upvoted! but does only providing read access also mean that the person cannot update records or insert records?

Comment: That's right, you need to create a new role manually and apply it, That means, A new role having all rights of ReadWrite but dropcollection.